# Can't log in to wireless network except under certain(inconvenient) conditions

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I've recently switched my OS from Windows to Ubuntu, and I am having troubles with connecting to the wireless network in my house.  I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed as the only OS on my computer.  When I boot up, no matter how many times I try, it just prompts me over and over and over for my network password.

I've got a process to get it to work, and it very consistently does so.  I put in an Ubuntu 10.04 Live CD, then I log in to the network.  It works the first time, every time.  Then I reboot back into 11.10, and then it logs in automatically.  I've had Ubuntu installed for about 10 days now, and this happens every single time.  I would rather not go through this process every time I boot up my computer.

My wireless adapter is: `Atheros Communications Inc. AR5008 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`

Comment: you need to go into the wireless network properties and save your password.

Comment: @Shark: It's saved already.  When it prompts me for the password, the password is already there.  It just fails to log in when I click connect, unless I go through the process I outlined in my question, at which point, it doesn't even prompt me, it just connects automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Before you solve the problem with your wireless. Try wicd first and see if it works :) It's a better wireless manager.

> http://wicd.sourceforge.net/download.php